# C# Pad string with spaces font dependent

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts

I'm trying to write something that will pad a list of strings so every string is the same size
Padding with spaces is fairly straightforward, you just get the maximum length and pad with spaces until they are equal

However my issue is with fonts that are not equal-width.

For example if we had

aa

WWW

we would pad aa with one space and get

aa

WWW

Because these fonts are not equal width they do not work.

I have written a script that tries to calculate the physical size of the string in question and pad with spaces until the sizes are equal.

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\ben.bodie\Desktop\FontPaddingTest.txt");
        var lines = sr.ReadToEnd().Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
        sr.Close();
        sr.Dispose();
        var max = 0;
        var spacesize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(" ", new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 7.8f));
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            var size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(line, new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 7.8f));
            max = Math.Max(max, size.Width);
        }
        foreach(var line in lines)
        {
            var newline = line;
            var size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(newline, new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 7.8f));
            var width = size.Width;
            int spacestoadd = 0;
            while(max-10 > width)
            {
                newline = " " + newline;
                width = width + spacesize.Width;
                spacestoadd++;
            }
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(newline, spacestoadd);
        }
```

However as you can see, this did not work

[image: MyImage]

Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: You can't just right justify the column and let the DataGridView do the hard work?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately i can't just right justify, im doing something complicated with it afterwards that includes turning this datagridview into a text file that needs to be padded with the spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done some tinkering with this and think i've fixed it

Instead of adding the size of the space, i am instead recalculating the size at every iteration of the loop where i add spaces

```
var newline = line;
            var size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(newline, new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 7.8f));
            var width = size.Width;
            int spacestoadd = 0;
            while(max-10 > width)
            {
                newline = " " + newline;
                 size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(newline, new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 7.8f));
                 width = size.Width;
                spacestoadd++;
            }
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(newline, spacestoadd);
```

[image: MyImage]

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a unicode for a different [Spaces](http://jkorpela.fi/chars/spaces.html), some are entirely universal and not font dependent.